# How to set file permissions using java NIO2 on Windows?

Tags: java, file, permissions, nio2

Are there any ways of setting file permissions using java8 NIO2 on Windows different from this?

```
file.setReadable(false, false);
file.setExecutable(false, false);
file.setWritable(false, false);
```

Comment: Why? Is that not suitable for you?

Comment: Possibly through [`AclFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html).

Comment: Kayaman - I checked it on my own system and can't see any differences(right-click popup menu->properties->security), like nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

The `File` methods that set various attributes: `setExecutable`, `setReadable`, `setReadOnly`, `setWritable` are replaced by the `Files` method [setAttribute(Path, String, Object, LinkOption...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute(java.nio.file.Path,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)).

**Usage Example:**

```java
public void setFileAttributes() throws IOException {
  Path path = ...

  UserPrincipal user = path.getFileSystem().getUserPrincipalLookupService().lookupPrincipalByName("user");
  AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);
  AclEntry entry = AclEntry.newBuilder()
          .setType(ALLOW)
          .setPrincipal(user)
          .setPermissions(Set.of(READ_DATA, EXECUTE, WRITE_DATA))
          .build();
  List<AclEntry> acl = view.getAcl();
  acl.add(0, entry);

  Files.setAttribute(path, "acl:acl", acl);
}
```

See [AclFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html) for more details.